# Material that only renders direct or bounce light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Is it possible to make a material that totally ignores indirect light, or direct light? In other words, could you render a material that looks only like the Direct Pass or the Indirect pass?

Comment: afaik, no. You can change the way it affects another materials (say, using light path / ray depth output), but not the way it is affected by other objects (received light). *(afaik means that I played with it up to 2.76. so newer ones may have the feature)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the compositor, assigning to your mesh an object index different than 0.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this method. Was hoping to find a way to do it in materials.

Comment: Very useful. Thumbed up.